# How to place layout behind the navigation bar, but NOT the status bar?

Tags: android-layout, android-fullscreen

I thought using [SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION) would place the layout only behind the navigation bar, but it also places the layout behind the top status bar. 
Is there a way to prevent the layout from being behind the status bar while keeping it behind the navigation bar?  Flag [SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) is not used, so the status bar is visible.